# Forcing .Extensions namespace to load when embedded DLL will need it

Tags: c#, dll, embedded-resource, dacpac

I'm building a utility that uses Microsoft's DACPAC libraries.  For the purpose of this tool, I want to embed all requisite libraries in the executable.  It appears that when I execute `DacServices.GenerateDeployScript()` it's trying to use the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions` library.  The library is also embedded, but perhaps isn't being resolved with my `EventHandler` the way other DLLs are.  My `EventHandler` is like this:

```
private static Assembly ResolveEventHandler(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        //Debugger.Break();
        String dllName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";

        var assem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        String resourceName = assem.GetManifestResourceNames().FirstOrDefault(rn => rn.EndsWith(dllName));
        if (resourceName == null) return null;
        using (var stream = assem.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        {
            Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
            return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
        }
    }
```

This works for resolving other items, but I believe that the likely issue is that the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac` namespace is making an execution time call to the `.Extensions` namespace and isn't able to resolve the namespace or the methods in it.  I could be wrong, but I'm not sure what else could be the cause.

The calls to methods and classes in `.Dac` itself are being handled fine, so I know the `EventHandler` is working properly.  I'm not really sure what to do and would appreciate any guidance.  I've tried `using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extenions` at the top of the .cs file, but since I don't directly call anything in that namespace, it's grey and probably is ignored by the compiler.

Thanks!

**Update:**

I made a call to the `.Extensions` namespace in the code to force it to be read into memory prior to the failing call, though it appears that it already was.  I set a breakpoint where the resolver kicks off.  Just prior to it failing, it's trying to resolve `.resource` for each DLL, e.g. `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.resource` and `Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.resource` - all for DLLs embedded in the executable.  The resolver doesn't see anything because there are no `.resource` files in the project, so nothing compiled into the manifest.  Aren't these supposed to just be resident in memory while a DLL is being utilized?  When the DLLs are all present in the same directory as the .exe, it functions fine, and also doesn't create temporary `.resource` files in the directory, so I'm unsure what I'm looking to resolve.

**Update 2:**

Using a PDB of the DAC libraries, it appears the failing line is:

`IOperation operation = DacServices.CreateDeploymentArtifactGenerationOperation(OperationResources.GenerateDeployScriptCaption, (ErrorManager errorManager) => this.CreatePackageToDatabaseDeployment(package.PackageSource, targetDatabaseName, dacDeployOption, errorManager), (IDeploymentController controller, DeploymentPlan plan, ErrorManager errorManager) => DacServices.WriteDeploymentScript(streamWriter, controller, plan, errorManager), cancellationToken1, dacLoggingContext);`

And the resulting exceptions are:

`The extension type Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Deployment.Internal.InternalDeploymentPlanExecutor could not be instantiated.`

and

`The extension type Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Deployment.Internal.InternalDeploymentPlanModifier could not be instantiated.`